# What should my function include to return the value of -1.0 if the wrong input is given?

Tags: c, visual-studio, function, call, return-value

Here is the project instructions:

> "Write a C program that includes a function of type double called divmaster accepts two double arguments (you must write the divmaster function). When called, your function will return the first argument divided by the second argument. Make sure your function includes a decision statement so that it can't divide by 0--if the caller attempts to divide by 0 the function should return a value of -1.0. Your program should call divmaster then display the value returned by the function. Test your function thoroughly then submit output using the arguments 22 and 3. Remember that a structured function should have only one return statement. "

I think I have most of the program correct, except im having difficulties with the function portion. We have not learned if else statements so I can't use those. My thoughts were a conditional while statement to return a value of -1.0 if 0 is entered. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
double divmaster(double x, double y);

int main(void)
{
    double i, j, value;

    printf("Please enter two numbers ");
    printf("the first number will be divded by the second. The value ");
    printf("will then be returned. Enter q to quit\n");

    while (scanf("%d%d", &i, &j) == 2)
    {
        value = divmaster(i, j);
        printf("%d divded by %d is %.6f\n", i, j, value);
        printf("Please enter the next paid of numbers or q to quit.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

    double divmaster(double x, double y)
    {

        while (y <= 0);
        printf("-1.0");


    }

}
```

Comment: `while (y <= 0);` is either an infinite loop or no loop at all... your function prints doesn't return anything, and should not loop _at all_

Comment: I understand, the function is not complete. I'm just listing what I have and my thoughts for clarification.

Comment: I'd do `return y<=0 ? -1.0 : y;`

Comment: *"When called, your function will return the first argument divided by the second argument."* So start with the basic functionality, and then modify the function to deal with the edge cases. But the job of reporting an error to the user does not belong in that function. It informs the *caller*, with `return -1.0;` It's a poorly devised task though: there does not seem to be a restriction on providing negative arguments, for example `1.0` and `-1.0`.

Comment: I need the function to divide the users input and return a value of -1.0 if the caller attempts to divide by 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has few major problems:

1. String format of `scanf` and `printf` is wrong, `%d` format takes an int, and you put a double as argument, the right format for double is `%lf`
2. You should be using a separator between each formats.
3. Your function divmaster is missing a `return` statement.

Here's what your code should look like after fixing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
double divmaster(double x, double y);

int main(void)
{
    double i, j, value;

    printf("Please enter two numbers ");
    printf("the first number will be divded by the second. The value ");
    printf("will then be returned. Enter q to quit\n");

    while (scanf("%lf %lf", &i, &j) == 2)
    {
        value = divmaster(i, j);
        printf("%lf divded by %lf is %.6lf\n", i, j, value);
        printf("Please enter the next pair of numbers or q to quit.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

double divmaster(double x, double y)
{

    if (0.0f == y)
        return -1.0f;
    else
        return x / y;
}
```

If you can't use if else statement, using while statement is also possible

```
while (0.0f == y)
    return -1.0f;

return x/y;
```

The correct format for each type are defined in the manual for each of these functions
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. However I can't use if else statements as we have not covered them in the course yet.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I would up vote but I am not at the level to do so currently.